# @vue/test-utils how to capture custom emit from child component

Tags: vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

I'm trying to unit test a component that has a child component called `<ButtonStandard>` which captures a click event and emits a custom event called `pressed`.

The parent component captures the `pressed` event and runs a method `methods.toggleArchive`.

I am trying to test that the correct method is run when a specific `<ButtonStandard>` is clicked.

The component I'm trying to test:

```
<script setup>
   ///
       const methods = {
            //toggle archive for this chat
            toggleArchive(){
                router.visit(route('conversation.toggleArchive',props.conversation.id));
            }
       }
</script>
<template>
    ///
            <ButtonStandard
                @pressed="methods.toggleArchive"
                dusk="inbox_toggle_archive"
            >
                Archive
            </ButtonStandard>
</template>
```

And my test:

```
 it("should call toggle_archive route when clicked", () => {

    //ARRANGE
    const methods = {
        toggleArchive : vi.fn(() => console.log('success'))
    };


    //ACT
    const wrapper = mount(ConversationStatus, {
        propsData: {
            conversation :  testConversation,
            showButtons : true
        }
    });

    //ASSERT

    expect(wrapper.find('[dusk="inbox_toggle_archive"]').exists()).toBe(true);
    wrapper.find('[dusk="inbox_toggle_archive"]').trigger('click');
    expect(methods.toggleArchive).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you land here with a similar problem, it turns out my issue with calling `trigger('click')` on my child component was because my `@click` listener was not on the root element in the child component

```
<template >

    <ToolTip :tooltip="tooltip message">
        <div ref="button" @click="clicked">
            <slot />
        </div>
    </ToolTip>

</template>
```

Moving it to the root element resolved it

```
<template >

    <ToolTip :tooltip="tooltip message" @click="clicked">
        <div ref="button">
            <slot />
        </div>
    </ToolTip>

</template>
```